# In order to parallelize a for loop, how to use concurrent.future for having 1 reused ᴛᴄᴘ connection per thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

Using `concurrent.futures` one can do this :

```
import pandas,concurrent.futures,urllib.request

URLS = ['http://some-made-up-domain.com/sifhzfhihrffhzs',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/rthrgfgd',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/gsezeraz',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/gfsrgerfg',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/sdfgdfdfh']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

result=[]
# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            result.append(future.result())
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
# Save for later use in different scripts
pandas.to_pickle(result,'result.pickle')
```

But now, since all requests are made to the same website (I have in reality 80,000 URLs), **how to reuse the underlying connections** ? I’m meaning having 1 connection per worker thread where each thread is reusing the connection across URL calls ?
The problem is I failed to find how to initialize an Object (representing a connection) one time per worker thread and initialize it in a way the variable name remain common to all threads (said thread local storage).

I’m using Linux and Python3.9.

Comment: unless you have some sort of login or redirect you have to go through, there isn't really such a thing as a reusable connection in http. it's all request-response

Comment: @Nullman I was speaking reusing ᴛᴄᴘ connection of course. In my real code, a connection is created through `w3 = HTTPProvider("https://cloudflare-eth.com")` and each subsequent use of w3 is reusing the same open port. The problem is if I still label the variable `w3` all threads will use the same w3\connection since the variable name would be the same.

Comment: you could assign an `HTTPProvider` per thread. you can access information about the current thread with `threading.current_thread()`. you could porbably achieve this with the `initializer` parameter of `ThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: @Nullman **assigning an `HTTPProvider` per thread is what I want to do with my question**. But the problem is handling the variable name in the code : If I still label it `w3` all threads will use the same connection. *I would need an initializer example with `ThreadPoolExecutor` which initializes a variable/Object* in order to understand.

Comment: If the variable is not global it would not be shared.  Also see the python library documentation for thread-local data.